# How to calculate the mean value across groups of data

Tags: python, pandas

I have this pandas DataFrame `df`:

```
Station   DateTime               Record
A         2017-01-01 00:00:00    20
A         2017-01-01 01:00:00    22  
A         2017-01-01 02:00:00    20
A         2017-01-01 03:00:00    18
B         2017-01-01 00:00:00    22
B         2017-01-01 01:00:00    24
```

I want to estimate the average `Record` per `DateTime` (basically per hour) across stations `A` and `B`. If either `A` or `B` have no record for some `DateTime`, then the `Record` value should be considered as 0 for this station.

It can be assumed that `DateTime` is available for all hours for at least one `Station`.

This is the expected result:

```
DateTime               Avg_Record
2017-01-01 00:00:00    21
2017-01-01 01:00:00    23  
2017-01-01 02:00:00    10
2017-01-01 03:00:00    9
```

Comment: Could you explain the output? How did you get `21` for `2017-01-01 00:00:00`?

Comment: `df.groupby('DateTime').Record.mean()` would give you what you said you wanted, but not what you provided as expected result.

Comment: i guess there should be a method to calculate mean along some axis in one line

Comment: @Vishnudev: It's an average between 20 (A record) and 22 (B record) for the same DateTime. Sorry, if it was not clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
g = df.groupby('DateTime')['Record']
df_out = g.mean()
m = g.count() == 1
df_out.loc[m] = df_out.loc[m] / 2
df_out = df_out.reset_index()
```

Or an uglier one-liner:

```
df = df.groupby('DateTime')['Record'].apply(
      lambda x: x.mean() if x.size == 2 else x.values[0]/2
      ).reset_index()
```

Proof:

```
import pandas as pd

data = '''\
Station   DateTime               Record
A         2017-01-01T00:00:00    20
A         2017-01-01T01:00:00    22  
A         2017-01-01T02:00:00    20
A         2017-01-01T03:00:00    18
B         2017-01-01T01:00:00    22
B         2017-01-01T02:00:00    24'''

fileobj = pd.compat.StringIO(data)
df = pd.read_csv(fileobj, sep='\s+', parse_dates=['DateTime'])

# Create a grouper and get the mean
g = df.groupby('DateTime')['Record']
df_out = g.mean()

# Divide by 2 where only 1 input exist
m = g.count() == 1
df_out.loc[m] = df_out.loc[m] / 2

# Reset index to get a dataframe format again
df_out = df_out.reset_index()

print(df_out)
```

Returns:

```
    DateTime   Record
0   2017-01-01 00:00:00 10.0
1   2017-01-01 01:00:00 22.0
2   2017-01-01 02:00:00 22.0
3   2017-01-01 03:00:00 9.0
```